# Can I use gasoline as a non-polar solvent?

Tags: solvents, polarity, extraction

I was wondering if I can use gasoline for a non-polar extraction of organic substances instead of prescribed diethyl ether, which is a bit hard to get in my country. If not, are there any products that can be found at hardware stores for example and can be used as a non-polar solvent?

Answer (score 1):

Gasoline is a mixture of several compounds, paraffins, cycloalkanes, and olefins (alkenes), the purification can be a challenge.

Comment: Then again, maybe you don't need any purification.

Comment: Is there anything you would suggest?

Comment: Actually, I will not. The extracted solution will be thrown away. Can I use it then?

Comment: Try ethyl acetate or acetone. Or you use gasoline and see what happens. Try with samll amount so you don't have to synthesis again and again.

Comment: This sort of mixture used to be called pet. ether and was common in labs for e.g. the non-polar component of chromatography eluent. There will be some things that are ether soluble but insoluble in gasoline but otherwise I don't see why you should not use it.

Comment: @Waylander If I'd use acetone, will it dissolve some polar compounds too, as it is a bit polar? Because I need to keep it for the next phase of extraction.

Comment: Acetone is more polar than ether and certainly there will be substances dissolved by acetone that are ether insoluble. Guess you won't know until you try whether the materials you're working with are among them.

Comment: If you are extracting with diethyl ether because of its non-polarity and not because of specific interactions with the ether group, and if you have access to it, try chloroform. Its polarity is very very similar to that of dimethyl ether.

Alternatively, toluene and turpentine are non-polar solvents that you can buy off the shelves.